# Breeze extract columns from DenseMatrix based on list

Tags: scala, matrix, scientific-computing

I just started working with Breeze in Scala and I am trying to figure out how to extract columns from a DenseMatrix where the column indexes that I want to extract are in a list.  For example, if you want to extract column 1,3 and 6 from a numpy array `myArray`in Python you can write

```
myArray[:,[1,3,6]]
```

In Breeze I have tried something similar

```
myArray(::,(1,3,6))
```

but it creates a syntax error.  I have looked at the [Breeze Linear Algebra Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Linear-Algebra-Cheat-Sheet) and but I only see the functionality to extract individual columns or contiguous columns.  Is there any way to directly specify the columns that I want to extract as in my example?

Comment: Would not something like `DenseMatrix(::, Seq(1, 3, 6))` work in this case?

Comment: That gives the error `Error:(18, 22) could not find implicit value for parameter canSlice: breeze.linalg.support.CanSlice2[breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Double],collection.immutable.::.type,Seq[Int],Result]
  myArray(::,Seq(0,1)))
                     ^`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem; the fix that I found was to import numerics as well as linalg from breeze:

```
import breeze.numerics._
```

It's mentioned at the top of the cheat sheet you found, but it's very easy to miss, especially if you've searched for a particular operation (what happened to me).

Answer (score 0):

We assign a dense matrix "dm" with the following contents:

```
import breeze.linalg._
val dm = DenseMatrix((0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
                     (8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15),
                     (16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23),
                     (24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31))

dm

0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
```

If we want to extract columns of a matrix (e.g. 1,3,6), we could extract a part of matrix with columns indexing

```
dm(::,IndexedSeq(1,3,6))

1   3   6
9   11  14
17  19  22
25  27  30
```

or rows indexing

```
dm(IndexedSeq(1,3),::)

8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15
24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
```

Thank you. Please feel free to comment

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer so that it may be helpfull also for other developers?

Comment: Updated the answer, hope this help